# Rails 5 - Stripe JS not refreshing after submit

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I have a payment form that has the following JS to generate a stripe token.

```
var form = $( "#new_subscription" );
form.validate();

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#new_subscription').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    $form.find('#formSubmit').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#new_subscription');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('.payment-errors').removeClass('hidden');
    $form.find('#formSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $form.find('.payment-errors').addClass('hidden');
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripe_token" />').val(token));
    // Remove Stripe cc fields
    $("[data-stripe=number]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=cvc]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=exp-year]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=exp-month]").remove();
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

in my controller, I have:

```
if !@subscription.errors.blank?
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @subscription_item = SubscriptionItem.new(subscription_item_params)
  flash.now[:error] = @subscription.errors[:base][0]
  render :new
```

When I use Stripe [test cc number](https://stripe.com/docs/testing) `4000000000000341`, it renders the correct `Payment Declined` error message on the new subscription form. And in the Stripe dashboard, it shows a failed payment associated with this card.

However, if I then enter a test card number that should successfully charge (`4000000000000077`) and submit, I get the same error as before. The test charges in the dashboard show that it is still trying to use the same card.

It's only after a page refresh that the form will send the correct card.

I'm not understanding why my page is sending the card number from the first submission when I enter a new card.

Comment: because turbolinks?

Comment: @victorhazbun don't think so. I removed turbolinks

Comment: The only difference I can see from mine is I have `event.preventDefault();` to prevent form submission in mine and don't even hit the Rails Controller if the Stripe token comes back with errors.  If you're interested you can take a look at my JS [here](https://github.com/trueinviso/unity/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/unity/stripe_payment_form.js).